# One of my NPCs I was supposed to escort died. Do they respawn?

Tags: dying-light

I let a NPC named Nick Pesto die. Is it true that he will respawn later or have I missed out on the reward for saving him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to leave the area and he should be back shortly. I had this happen a couple of times in my own game (not sure if it was the same guy or not, but it should behave the same).